# c# dynamic change panel's width from left side

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to dynamic change panel's width. But it grows from left to right.
So i want change them to grow from right to left.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
timer2.Start();
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int x;
panel2.Size+= new Size(10, 0);
x = panel2.Size.Width;
if (x >=200 )
{
timer2.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Which framework are you using? WinForms/WPF/...

Answer (score 1):

Change the position at the same time and by the same amount as the size and you're all set.

Comment: Nice thought! but i want to grow my panel from right to left. I want make something like book change pafe effect.

Comment: So? Same procedure! `panel2.Location.Offset(-10, 0);` - Of course for any effect there must be content and it and its alignment/docking must also be considered; in this case anchor it right!